# Unboxing a boxed float to an int

Tags: c#, boxing

I'm preparing for an exam and stumbled over a question regarding boxing/unboxing.
I always thought if i box let's say a float like this:

```
float x = 4.5f;
object o = x;
```

If a want a value type variable back from `o`, I will have to unbox it to a float.

```
float y = (float)o;
```

This should throw an exception:

```
int z = int(o);
```

If I want to cast the value stored in `o` to an int I will have to unbox it first and cast afterwards like this:

```
int z = (int)(float)o;
```

Now the question i stumbled upon:

Suppose you have a method like this:

```
public static void FloorTemperature(float degrees) {
    object degreesRef = degrees;
    `xxx`
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

You need to ensure the application does not throw exceptions on invalid conversions. Which code segment should you insert for `xxx` (I think invalid conversion are invalid cast exceptions):

(a) `int result = (int)degreesRef;`
(b) `int result = (int)(float)degreesRef;`

The correct solution is (a), but to me (b) looks correct. So can you please enlighten me? What am I missing?

Kind regards

Comment: Well have you tried to validate whether or not `a` works? This looks pretty easy to test, and indeed it looks like it should be `b`.

Comment: unfortunately I don't have a visual studio installed on the machine i have with me :/

Comment: So wait until you *are* on a suitable machine. Or use csharppad.com. Or if the machine you're on has .NET but not VS, use Notepad and csc.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thank you Jon Skeet, I didn't know about csharppad.com yet. Using the shell there I could find out that indeed (a) is an invalid cast and (b) is working fine!

Comment: the first one causes an exception.

Comment: Who told you that (a) is correct?

Comment: @RickDavin I found some example questions from "ensurepass" on the net, these questions come with 'correct' answers.

Answer (score 5):

You aren't missing anything

The answer should be (b) because:

(a) throws an exception since you are trying to cast `object` to `int`.

(b) is correct since you first cast it to `float` then you cast it to `int` which rounds it but doesn't throw an exception.